# May I replace a matrix with its eigenvalue in an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Lets have a matix A of $n\times n$, in the follwing equation $A^3 + yA = O$ where y is a random number and O is a matrix of the same size with only zeros. May I replace a matrix with its eigenvalue in an equation and if so then why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A^3+yA = O$

Let $\vec{v}$ be the eigenvector with $\lambda$ be the eigenvalue.

$$A^3\vec{v}+yAv=\vec{0}$$

$$(\lambda^3+y\lambda) \vec{v}=\vec{0}$$

Since $\vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$

$$\lambda^3+y\lambda = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mu$ be an eigenvalue of $A$, hence, with some $x \ne 0$:

$Ax= \mu x$. Then we get

$(A^3+yA)x= \mu^3x+y \mu x=(\mu^3+y \mu) x$. This shows that $\mu^3+y \mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3+yA$. Since $A^3+yA=0$, we get

$\mu^3+y \mu=0.$